# Finding blank data in table

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a tbl with data as follows:

```
print(Plate_Number)
# A tibble: 513 × 4
   Plate Row   Column Count
   <int> <chr>  <int> <int>
 1     1 A          1     6
 2     1 A          2     5
 3     1 A          3    20
 4     1 A          4    11
 5     1 A          5     5
 6     1 A          6    16
 7     1 A          7    12
 8     1 A          8     7
 9     1 A          9    24
10     1 A         10     9
# … with 503 more rows
```

This table contains "Plates" 1 -> 6. For each "Plate" There is "Row" A - > B and "Column" 1 -> 12 for a complete dataset.

However, the data set isn't complete. Sporadically data will be missing, for example Plate 2 may have only 11 "Column" data points as Column 8 is missing.

here is an example of where the data isn’t complete:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Plate Row   Column Count
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 E          1    10
 2     1 E          3     3
 3     1 E          4     5
 4     1 E          5    19
 5     1 E          7     5
 6     1 E          8     9
 7     1 E          9    25
 8     1 E         10    10
 9     1 E         11     3
10     1 E         12     7
```

I want to locate these values and fill the "Count" value as 0. The example is for plate 1, row E where column 2 and 6 are missing. I want to append the table to fill in the missing table rows with "count" of 0.

Is there a way to code this in R?

Comment: Use `tidyr::complete`. Please provide a reproducible data so that we can answer your question more completely.

Comment: Please show an example that includes missing values, using `dput`. As it stands right now it's not clear if the whole row is missing, if there're NAs or something else.

Comment: Great point, I've added an example to the original question

Answer (score 0):

As Maël said, you can use `complete()`:

```
tidyr::complete(Plate_Number, Plate = 1:6, Row = LETTERS[1:2], Column = 1:12, fill = list(Count = 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 144 × 4
   Plate  Row   Column Count
    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1 A          1     1
 2      1 A          2     0
 3      1 A          3     0
 4      1 A          4     0
 5      1 A          5     0
 6      1 A          6     0
 7      1 A          7     0
 8      1 A          8     0
 9      1 A          9     0
10      1 A         10     0
# ℹ 134 more rows
```

Data:

```
Plate_Number <- data.frame(
    Plate = 1,
    Row = "A",
    Column = 1, 
    Count = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, This ones on me sorry, I don't think this is quite right, see my edit with an example of a non-complete dataset

Comment: What is the desired answer for the example in your question? Is it just to complete the missing `Column`s, and ignore the missing `Row`s ? And what about the Plates?

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help Mark, 

I'm a scientist, for this experiment I have 6 "96 well plates" that look like [this] (https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/96-well-plates/10106131). As you can see each plate has row identifiers A -> H and column identifiers 1 -> 12. 

I have quantified each 6 plates where "count" is the output. The problem comes when a well has no signal, the output needs to be a 'Count" of 0 however, the data I have outputted above, just ignores these.

I need to complete the dataset by filling the missing gaps with a count of 0

Comment: right, okay, that gives me more context, without necessarily answering my questions (e.g. 
What is the desired answer for the example in your question?)

Comment: I still don't know what the issue is with my answer. Hopefully though you have an idea of how `complete()` works and can create something which works for you now though? ?